# return intercept from sklearn enet_path

Tags: scikit-learn

When using functions like sklearn.linear_model.lasso_path, if return_models is set to False, the returned values are the alphas and the coefficients. However, the intercepts for the path are NOT returned, which means that the coefficients cannot be applied to predict new data. Alternatively, one can ask to return models, but it seems like returning models will be deprecated soon, from the warning I got :

> DeprecationWarning: Use enet_path(return_models=False), as it returns the coefficients and alphas instead of just a list of models as previously `lasso_path`/`enet_path` did. `return_models` will eventually be removed in 0.15, after which, returning alphas and coefs will become the norm.

So, how can one get the full path inclusing coefficients, alphas and intercepts?

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack is to append your **X** matrix with a new column of 1s. The intercept then just becomes one of the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Appending a new column of 1s to **X** will penalize the new column, however the intercept term is normally not penalized in the Lasso. I concluded that `sklearn.linear_model.lasso_path` assumes the response variable is centered with the following example:

```
remove_shift = True

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
               columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


train_x = df.iloc[:,:-1]
train_y = df.iloc[:,-1]
if remove_shift:
    y_shift = train_y.mean()
    train_y -= y_shift

# Provide a single alpha value (0.5) for the path
print("Lasso path solution:")
_, coefs_lasso, _ = lasso_path(train_x, train_y, alphas=[.5])

print("Coefficients:", coefs_lasso)

print("Lasso solution:")

my_model = Lasso(max_iter=1000, alpha = .5, fit_intercept = False).fit(train_x, train_y)

print("Model coefs:", my_model.coef_)
print("Intercept:",my_model.intercept_)
```

This also requires to use Lasso with `fit_intercept = False`. So centering the response variable before calling `lasso_path` is enough IMO.